# How to fix "req.files print null issue" in node and express

Tags: express

**Issue in image upload in node express by express-fileupload**

I have app.js file and a router file and a view file. When I upload an image and console (req.files) it gives null. I am using express-fileupload package manager.

**app.js**

```
const express   = require('express');
const path      = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

// Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Express Fileupload middleware
app.use(fileUpload());

// Set Routes

var adminProducts   = require('./routes/admin_products.js');
app.use('/admin/products', adminProducts);

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port);
});
```

**router/admin_product.js**

```
router.post('/add-product', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.files); // Prints null
});
```

**add-product.ejs**

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/products/add-product" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="img">
        <img src="#" id="imgPreview" alt="">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app.js file we have to give the path of folder where image will save -

```
app.use(bodyParser({uploadDir:'./public/product_images'}));
```